# Is There a Way to Know if an Id Exists Without Querying?

Tags: query, custom-object, salesforce-id

Is there a way to know if an Object ID exists in a sandbox without querying for it?

Sometimes we store ID's in Metadata/Custom Settings and I'm curious if there is a way to know if the ID exists without doing a query like `[SELECT Id FROM Object WHERE Id =: idValue]` and checking for `null`. If there is a way to check it without using up a query I'd prefer it.

Comment: Not an answer to this question specifically, but consider using External ID fields when possible, since you can associate records more-or-less automatically when using them. This reduces dependencies on ID values.

Comment: If real-time check is not a priority, probably a Schedulable apex to check them periodically and send alert if any invalid ID is found might work?

Comment: "Querying" is how you find out what's in a database, so no.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is NO

A far better practice is to store API names in custom settings/custom metadata and query for the resource by apiName in the code:

- API Names are more transparent than IDs
- Custom metadata values can be deployed
- Sandboxes created from PROD that include ID values might be broken if the IDs point at data records not present in the sandbox (such as typical in a Developer-type sandbox)
- A failure to find a resource at runtime can come with an admin friendly message indicating the apiName of the resource you are looking for along with the sobjectType. This speeds up the fix cycle.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, there is a way to do this using dml (`update new MyObj(Id = 'targetId');`) and a try/catch block.

...but exceptions as flow control is a bad idea, and if the Id does exist you'd likely end up using more than a single query anyway.

This is such a poor idea that it's hardly worth mention, and I will not be providing a code example (so as to not encourage people to try to use it).

So *technically* yes, but *practically* no.

Comment: Technically that's still a query.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica How do you figure? In the best (but still bad) case, this approach would not consume any queries that count towards the governor limit (i.e. running `system.debug(Limits.getQueries());` before and after would show the same number).

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be checking for multiple Ids against the same object, and that object's table size is relatively small, you could query for the whole table into a `Map<Id, sObject>` and check if a specific Id exists in the map keys. This would reduce the need of multiple queries.

One query will be required though.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the Platform Cache. (not sure of the licensing implications here)

It doesn't stop a query, but it does limit the number of queries.

e.g.

```
public class RecordInfoCache implements Cache.CacheBuilder {
    
    public SObject doLoad(Id recordId) {
        SObject theRecord;
        
        if(recordId != null) {
            List<SObject> obejctList = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM ' + recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() + ' WHERE Id = :recordId');
            
            theRecord = obejctList.size() == 1 ? obejctList[0] : null;
            
        }
        return theRecord;
    }
}
```

You can then get the record:

```
User batman = (User) Cache.Org.get(RecordInfoCache.class, '0057000000452I1');
```

If the record exists, the first time you call this method it will perform a query, but it will then store it in a cache, meaning subsequent calls will fetch it from the cache instead.

If the record doesn't exist, I don't think the cache can store a null value, so it will perform a query each time.  I think this will be ok because I'm assuming you're trying to limit the number of queries when there is data.
(Or more to the point, you're trying to not perform a query just to handle the occasion where there is no record)

Having said this, I'd still highly recommend not storing Ids.  See cropredy's answer.

Comment: In addition to any potential licensing concerns, this approach would only be able to store a somewhat limited number of records. Might be worth doing the math to increase the value of this answer. Although also any other use of the Cache would obviously eat into that.